# Are there any restrictions on which houses can be combined in a deck in Keyforge?

Tags: keyforge

I keep finding myself speculating which house combos are cool and would be optimal to play with. But at the same time both my decks and my friends decks are extremely similar in house compositions (for example it appears that Mars combos are more common than Brobnar)

I know enough statistics to grasp that my sample pool is way too small to draw any conclusions but still I am wondering whether or not there are any restrictions on which house combos are generated by the deck generator.

Answer (score 4):

No. Not only is no combination blocked, each combination is equally likely.

Here are the number of decks registered on the [Keyforge Compendium](https://keyforge-compendium.com/decks) for each combination of houses:

[image: Untamed][image: Logos][image: Sanctum]: 23,360 (3.1%)
[image: Shadows][image: Untamed][image: Brobnar]: 23,363 (3.1%)
[image: Shadows][image: Untamed][image: Logos]: 23,435 (2.8%)
[image: Untamed][image: Brobnar][image: Logos]: 23,454 (2.7%)
[image: Untamed][image: Brobnar][image: Sanctum]: 23,606 (2.1%)
[image: Untamed][image: Logos][image: Dis]: 23,607 (2.1%)
[image: Mars][image: Shadows][image: Untamed]: 23,636 (2.0%)
[image: Mars][image: Untamed][image: Logos]: 23,639 (2.0%)
[image: Untamed][image: Dis][image: Sanctum]: 23,723 (1.6%)
[image: Mars][image: Untamed][image: Dis]: 23,729 (1.6%)
[image: Shadows][image: Untamed][image: Dis]: 23,810 (1.2%)
[image: Untamed][image: Brobnar][image: Dis]: 23,818 (1.2%)
[image: Mars][image: Untamed][image: Sanctum]: 23,857 (1.0%)
[image: Shadows][image: Untamed][image: Sanctum]: 23,876 (1.0%)
[image: Mars][image: Untamed][image: Brobnar]: 24,053 (0.2%)
[image: Mars][image: Brobnar][image: Dis]: 24,230 (0.5%)
[image: Shadows][image: Brobnar][image: Dis]: 24,265 (0.6%)
[image: Shadows][image: Logos][image: Sanctum]: 24,280 (0.7%)
[image: Shadows][image: Brobnar][image: Logos]: 24,294 (0.8%)
[image: Brobnar][image: Logos][image: Sanctum]: 24,318 (0.9%)
[image: Mars][image: Shadows][image: Logos]: 24,330 (0.9%)
[image: Mars][image: Shadows][image: Dis]: 24,350 (1.0%)
[image: Brobnar][image: Dis][image: Sanctum]: 24,359 (1.0%)
[image: Brobnar][image: Logos][image: Dis]: 24,386 (1.1%)
[image: Shadows][image: Brobnar][image: Sanctum]: 24,397 (1.2%)
[image: Mars][image: Shadows][image: Sanctum]: 24,408 (1.2%)
[image: Mars][image: Brobnar][image: Logos]: 24,420 (1.3%)
[image: Shadows][image: Dis][image: Sanctum]: 24,455 (1.4%)
[image: Mars][image: Shadows][image: Brobnar]: 24,488 (1.6%)
[image: Mars][image: Dis][image: Sanctum]: 24,512 (1.7%)
[image: Shadows][image: Logos][image: Dis]: 24,583 (2.0%)
[image: Mars][image: Logos][image: Sanctum]: 24,625 (2.1%)
[image: Mars][image: Logos][image: Dis]: 24,700 (2.4%)
[image: Logos][image: Dis][image: Sanctum]: 24,733 (2.6%)
[image: Mars][image: Brobnar][image: Sanctum]: 24,759 (2.7%)

(The percentage is the difference from the average, as a percentage of the average.)

Comment: While not statistically significant, I do find it interesting all the Untamed decks are in the bottom 15 combinations.

Comment: @SocioMatt, There is a potential bias from self-reporting. (People with Untamed decks could be less likely to register them.)

Comment: Thanks for the figures.. That certainly answers the question. Could there be a geographical bias then?

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

[Keyforge Compendium](https://keyforge-compendium.com/decks) has a search feature that ties into decks registered in the app. Here is a breakdown by house combination of registered decks of all combinations including Mars (as of today):

- Mars/Shadows/Untamed: 23636
- Mars/Shadows/Borbnar: 24488
- Mars/Shadows/Logos: 24330
- Mars/Shadows/Dis: 24350
- Mars/Shadows/Sanctum: 24407
- Mars/Untamed/Brobnar: 24053
- Mars/Untamed/Logos: 23639
- Mars/Untamed/Dis: 23729
- Mars/Untamed/Sanctum: 23857
- Mars/Borbnar/Logos: 24420
- Mars/Borbnar/Dis: 24230
- Mars/Borbnar/Sanctum: 24759
- Mars/Logos/Dis: 24699
- Mars/Logos/Sanctum: 24625
- Mars/Dis/Sanctum: 24512

The high in this set is 24,759 and the low is 23,636, a difference of 1,123 decks. I spot checked some other house combinations that didn't include Mars and they were all in the same range:

- Shadows/Untamed/Brobnar: 23363
- Brobnar/Dis/Sanctum: 24359
- Untamed/Logos/Sanctum: 23360

This is probably enough to show that house combinations are fairly even distributed across the print run and there aren't house restrictions. Having said that, it appears there are restrictions on the number of cards that can appear in a deck, and possibly the combination of those cards:

- There are 0 decks with more than 1 copy of [Bait and Switch](https://keyforge-compendium.com/sets/1-cota/cards/267-bait-and-switch)
- There are 0 decks with both [Chota Hazri](https://keyforge-compendium.com/sets/1-cota/cards/349-chota-hazri) and [Key Charge](https://keyforge-compendium.com/sets/1-cota/cards/325-key-charge)